# Installing WordPress and MySQL on Server 2012

Tags: php, mysql, windows, wordpress

I am using Server 2012 R2. 
 I am trying to install WordPress through Web Platform Installer 4.6.  
I installed MySQL and WordPress successfully once but uninstalled them when something got hosed up.  The problem I have now is that MySQL will install successfully but WordPress fails to install.  
See picture  [image: Web Platform Installer] It is asking for a root password but the password I gave it, or any I can think of, works.  I did look to make sure the MySQL server is running. 
 I have searched Google and tried all the step suggested in multiple sites and now I'm banging my head.  I need to get around this of uninstall a hidden database or something.  
Any direction in accomplishing this would be appreciated

Here is the error log:

```
  DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9824573
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9824573 responded with 302
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Length: 175
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Expires: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:16:25 GMT
    Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webproductlist.xml
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:17:24 GMT


    DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
    Cache-Control: max-age=900
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    ETag: "0302d856d48cf1:0"
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
    VTag: 438585743600000000
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:17:25 GMT


    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-872341423.xml.temp
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webapplicationlist.xml
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
    Cache-Control: max-age=900
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    ETag: "c82af85b8e4ecf1:0"
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
    VTag: 791705041900000000
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:17:27 GMT


    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\751837351.xml.temp
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/webapplicationlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\751837351.xml'
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/mediaproductlist.xml
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
    Cache-Control: max-age=900
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    ETag: "e62862cd116dce1:0"
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
    VTag: 791705041900000000
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:17:28 GMT


    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1953942818.xml.temp
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/mediaproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\1953942818.xml'
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/ToolsProductList.xml
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/ToolsProductList.xml responded with 304
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
    Cache-Control: max-age=900
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    ETag: "056483d104dcf1:0"
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
    VTag: 279767741800000000
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:17:28 GMT


    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-95717523.xml.temp
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/ToolsProductList.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-95717523.xml'
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/enterpriseproductlist.xml
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
    Cache-Control: max-age=900
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    ETag: "80838519a3fdce1:0"
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
    VTag: 791114243600000000
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:17:28 GMT


    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1709116680.xml.temp
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.6/enterpriseproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-1709116680.xml'
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9824573' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-872341423.xml'
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Length: 203
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Expires: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:16:28 GMT
    Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:17:28 GMT


    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-Encoding header: 'gzip'
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '22569'
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '75141'
    DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Error getting last-modified header, error code: 12150
    DownloadManager Warning: 0 : HttpQueryInfoWithRetry for HTTP_QUERY_LAST_MODIFIED failed.
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product WordPress (WordPress) to cart
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'WordPress'
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Users\nrandolph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WordPress\e2046dcec11454e023f842fc472929f1b00ef830\wordpress-3.8.1-IIS.zip instead of downloading from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.8.1-IIS.zip
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : User has canceled the current installation
```

[image]

Comment: where is the install error log ?

Comment: I just edited the question to include the log

Comment: is possible that you have some stuck process ! check if any proceses related to your install are running in the task manager !

Comment: I ended the tasks of the ones that appeared to be related and that didn't work either

Comment: can you connect to the mysql database using you cmd line client ? test  the connection

Comment: That doesn't work either, enter password and crashes because it wont accept it

Comment: so you have found the problem! now try to make you mysql to work first and then continue with your wordpress install !

Comment: if you need help ill be here

Comment: I already know that it wont download because of the database not connecting.  That wasn't even my question or problem.  I need to get around the "root" user password it wont accept

Comment: let me get this right ! can you connect to the database using you mysql client ? post the error msg it returns

Comment: No. There is no error message.  As I stated above, it crashes hard when I hit enter after I put in the password

Comment: there is always an erro msg ! or an erro log ! find the log ! look for this file 'my.ini' and see inside of it where is the error.log file

Comment: I just added an image to the question.  I searched the entire c drive and could not find that file

Comment: ok go to this path and see  what is in there c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql-version\ - the my.ini file should be there !!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress) doesn't install MySQL correctly.

Install MySQL manually from [MySQL.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) and then run the WPI again. It will use the version you installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found that on Azure (and this is probably true on Windows 2012 Server and Windows 10) the MSI must be installed using elevated permissions (e.g. run as administrator).  If you can't do this directly, run the MSI inside a batch file that is executed as an administrator.